# PUSH/POP in ARMv5 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, push, calling-convention

I'm new to ARMv5 assembly coding.

Suppose I wish to call a C function from my assembly code using CALL_VM_FUNCTION. My C function uses three arguments. Which registers do I save the arguments in before calling the C function? Is there a specific convention followed for this?

In addition to that, I want to ensure that before and after the C-function call is done, the registers retain the values. Would push and pop instructions take care of that issue fully?

Eg:

```
PUSH {a1-a4}  /*values held in registers a1-a4 are saved*/    
/*instruction to pass arguments in the registers for C function call*/    
CALL_VM_FUNCTION(C-function)
POP {a1-a4}
```

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Which OS, which version? The C calling convention differs across different software platforms...

Answer (score 1):

If you have data you need to keep in any of the call-clobbered registers, you must save them (e.g. with `push`) before making the call. This has nothing to do with argument passing; it's just to avoid having your own data clobbered by the callee. In particular, you must always save `lr` unless your function never returns.

As for how to pass arguments, it's not by pushing a1-a4 onto the stack. The first 4 integer/pointer arguments go in the a1-a4 *registers* directly. After that, they go on the stack. Things get a bit more complicated for floating point and aggregate types, so you'd best read the ABI:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf